# MS Access update query and inner join with string parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help me solve this problem in MS Access. I want to update my `user table` using the `statusid` that I will get in `userstatus table`.

This query properly work in MySQL. Why in MS Access not. Inner join with a parameter of string doesn't work.

```
UPDATE tbl_users AS us
  INNER JOIN tbl_userstatus AS ust ON ust.status = "Offline"  
SET us.statusid =  ust.statusid 
WHERE us.username = "francis";
```

Comment: what is the joining key between two tables

Comment: the joining key is the `statusid`. but I want to get the `statusid` from my table `tbl_userstatus` using the parameter `'Offline'`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this `JOIN expression not supported`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS Access, you can try:

```
UPDATE tbl_users AS us,   -- MS Access does not support explicit CROSS JOIN
       tbl_userstatus AS ust
    SET us.statusid =  ust.statusid 
    WHERE us.username = "francis" AND ust.status = "Offline";
```

In either database, you can use:

```
UPDATE tbl_users
    SET statusid =  (SELECT ust.statusid FROM tbl_userstatus AS ust ON ust.status = "Offline")
    WHERE username = "francis";
```

This are not *exactly* the same.  But I assume that `tbl_userstatus` has exactly one row with "Offline" -- in which case they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, assume `statusid` is the joining column between two tables and guess that you want to update `status` column of user table by using data `tbl_userstatus` of column  `status`

```
UPDATE us
SET    us.status =  ust.status 
FROM   tbl_users AS us
       INNER JOIN tbl_userstatus  AS ust  
              on us.statusid =  ust.statusid
         WHERE us.username = "francis"
```

Comment: What I want is to use a string in an `Inner Join` statement. Something like this `Inner Join table1 ON table1.column1 = 'myString'`. MS Access doesn't want this kind of query.